# Adding a humidifier with oval-shaped duct on return

Tags: humidifier

I have an oval return duct. Can I mount an Aprilaire 600 humidifier on supply side of furnace?

Comment: Welcome!  I think you mean [duct](https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=duct&form=HDRSC3) not [duck](https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=duck&form=HDRSC3).   You can press "Edit" above to fix this in your headline and question.  Also, while you're doing it, you could add a photo of your oval duct (just copy-paste in a jpg), and any information you have about the make/model of the duct.  That would be helpful.    There are probably adapters so you can connect rectangular and round things to it, and they are probably sold by the return-duct maker.

Comment: And make sure you have your [27B/6](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VRfoIyx8KfU).